# scipy stats missing way to modify alpha in two-sided t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, scipy

is there a way to change the alpha value from the standard 0.05 in the `ttest_ind()` function in Python? Compared to R, I don't see a way here to apply correction methods like Bonferroni or so.

Answer (score 1):

There is not, nor should there be. The function outputs a p-value, not a decision based on the p-value related to an $\alpha$ threshold. Therefore, the function has no notion of $\alpha$, not even $\alpha=0.05$.

Comment: This is exactly my thought. The question is quite strange but as long as it helps @Dennis and others ...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you are right!
I was slightly confused because in R one gets all on a silver plate (including correction functions)
Anyway, thanks for clarification!

;-)